# Problema Botón Stop Interfaz Gráfica Python

Tags: python, interfaz

tengo un problema con una interfaz grafica con Python en Customtkinter.Les hago un resumen Tengo dos botones,uno d start y otro d stop. Cada uno jala una función. Pero en el start está la función principal. Ya se q tengo q crear un hilo para q el programa siga funcionando pero no se como ejecutar la función del stop donde en cualquier momento pueda parar la función y el hilo. Sabes sobre algo de Eso?